# How does user with low rep address a locked post?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, locked-question

When a post is locked comments and edits are disabled. If a user has less than 20 rep the user cannot participate in chat. How can a user with low rep address a question of theirs which is locked?

Answer (score 3):

Meta is always a suitable venue for raising issues like "why is this question locked?" or "what do I need to do to get this question reopened?" or "I don't understand why I'm being downvoted into the basement here; help?".  Locking *should* be quite rare, so even if you think you "wouldn't want to bother folks on meta" for some of the others, please do bring it here.  If it was locked a while ago, it's entirely possible that the mods have just plain forgotten about it.  Or there may be a real reason that isn't explained clearly enough in comments, and if so we need to know so we can remedy that.

Comment: You do need 5 rep to participate on meta.

Comment: Oh right, meta's not completely available.  But 5 is a little easier than 20 -- get 2 edits approved, or ask one +1 question, and you're there.